# DateTime string in Ruby - how to make the time optional

Tags: ruby, datetime, datetime-format

Is there a way to parse the timestamp string of format "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS" *without cycling through several date-format strings*, so that the time will be optional.

Wishful-thinking examples:

```
"01/01/2014"       -> 01/01/2014 00:00:00
"01/01/2014 10:00" -> 01/01/2014 10:00:00
```

Tried to use `DateTime.strptime("01/01/14 12:00", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")` but obviously got an error because there are no seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the dates you are trying to parse are in the format `%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S` , with possibly missing hours, minutes, or seconds, the [`DateTime.parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-parse) method should do:

```
require 'date'

DateTime.parse("01/01/2014").to_s
# => "2014-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"

DateTime.parse("01/01/2014 10:00").to_s
# => "2014-01-01T10:00:00+00:00"

DateTime.parse("01/01/2014 10:00:30").to_s
# => "2014-01-01T10:00:30+00:00"
```

Comment: Is it locale-dependant please? For example, 01/03 will it always bring Mar, 1st and not Jan, 3rd?

Comment: Actually, asked the previous question in a separate post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482532/datetime-parse-in-ruby-is-it-deterministic-locale-dependent

Answer (score 5):

You could write a custom method using `case..when` construct and *pattern* as below :

```
require 'time'
require 'date'

def parse_date_time(string)
  case string
  when /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/
    DateTime.strptime( string, "%d/%m/%Y" )
  when /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}/
    DateTime.strptime( string, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M" )
  when /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/
    DateTime.strptime( string, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S" )
  end
end

parse_date_time('01/01/2014 10:00:12')
# => #<DateTime: 2014-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2456659j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

parse_date_time('12/07/2011')
# => #<DateTime: 2011-07-12T00:00:00+00:00 ((2455755j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```