# Is DateTime.parse() in Ruby dependent on locale?

Tags: ruby, datetime, datetime-format

I'm wondering regarding the output of the following example:
when parsing `01/03`, will it be resolved as `Mar, 1st` or `Jan, 3rd`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's *deterministic*, yes. A `rand` call in the parse function would be odd. ;-)

Comment: @deceze Thanks, fixed. Not sure I've phrased the question "optimally" :) Actually, some `rand()` implementations can be deterministic as well.

Comment: if it is just 01/03 then on Date parsing it returns 2014-01-03 and date.month returns 1. Whereas if it is 01/03/yyyy then Date.parse returns yyyy-03-01 and date.month returns 3

Comment: Ruby does not have any variable related to locale, so it cannot be.

Comment: If you know the order use `DateTime.strptime('01/03', '%d/%m')`

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is not locale dependent. Because Ruby is a *server-side* language and not a *client-side* language like JavaScript, Ruby uses the system clock from *your* web app server - and uses this information to calculate the time. Whatever timezone you have your system set to is what your Ruby app will use.

When parsing a date from a string, `DateTime` will make its best guess based on how the input is formatted:

```rb
DateTime.parse('01/03')
#=> Thu, 03 Jan 2019 00:00:00 +0000

DateTime.parse('2019/01/03')
#=> Thu, 03 Jan 2019 00:00:00 +0000

DateTime.parse('01/03/2019')
#=> Fri, 01 Mar 2019 00:00:00 +0000
```

You can also explicitly *tell* `DateTime` how you want your string parsed using `strptime`:

```rb
date = '01-03-2019'

DateTime.strptime(date, '%m-%d-%Y')
#=> Thu, 03 Jan 2019 00:00:00 +0000

DateTime.strptime(date, '%d-%m-%Y')
#=> Fri, 01 Mar 2019 00:00:00 +0000
```